# Import text file with letters and print their numbers

Tags: python, printing, numbers, letter

I have a text file containing letters in a list "a - z", i want to import that file and make VSC print out something like this:
Letter number 0 is a
Letter number 1 is b
Letter number 2 is c
I wanna do this in Visual Studio Code with python.
Anyone who can help with this?

Comment: Please show an attempt to code this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few hints:

a) Read the file using Python's "with open" statements

b) loop through the file using the "for" statement

c) for each character use ord() to get the ASCII code. As there is an offset between the ASCII value and the number you desire, simply substract the offset.